# Join C# DataTable with SQL Table

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, datatable

I have got `CSV` file from 3rd party and I have created DataTable from that file. I want to add one more column (`Id`) in DataTable from Database.

I have **primary-key-foreign-key** relationship between DataTable generated from `CSV` and one in Database. I am wondering whether I can join these 2 tables and get data?

I have already fetched through iteration over `CSV` DataTable and running `SELECT` query based on foreign key as below but it seems expensive one.

```
foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    // Get Id using select query and add it to newly created column
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you want to achieve. You want for every row in the csv-table get the data from database and then you want to add one column to your csv-table which value is set from the DB-data?

Comment: Create 2nd DataTable from database using Adapter.  then uisng linq to merge two DataTables.

Comment: @jdweng it seems better solution, thanks

Comment: How large is your DB table and how large is the DataTable?

Comment: If your table in DB is too large, write stored procedure that returns table, pass your `DataTable` to it, make your join, and return desired result.